# Python(pygame)で作ったゲームのAppleをSneakが食べたときのスコアが出ない＆バツボタンで抜け出せない

Tags: python, pygame

SneakGameでリンゴを食べた際にYummyと表示する処理を作ったのですが、
リンゴを食べても文字が表示されません。

ESCと×ボタンでゲームを閉じる処理を作ったのですが、なぜか×ボタンだけしか反応しません。
（ウィンドウクローズ）

```
from pygame import * 
from random import randint

init() 

N, M=30, 20
Scale=25
w,h=Scale*N, Scale*M
screen = display.set_mode((w,h)) 

Snake=[(5,5),(5,4),(5,3),(5,2),(5,1)]
Apple=[(23,6),(9,15),(14,7),(2,11)]

FIELD=Surface((w,h))
FIELD.fill((240,240,150))
for i in range(0,w,Scale):
    draw.line(FIELD,(0,0,0),(i,0),(i,h))
    draw.line(FIELD,(0,0,0),(0,i),(w,i))

def NewApple():
     if Snake[0] in Apple:
        i=Apple.index(Snake[0])
        Apple[i]=(randint(0,N),randint(0,M))
        Snake.append(Snake[-1])
def AppleDraw():
     for i in Apple:
        rect=(i[0]*Scale,i[1]*Scale,Scale-1,Scale-1)
        draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),rect)

(R,L,U,D)=range(4)
d=R
def tick():
      if d==R: x=1;y=0;
      if d==L: x=-1;y=0;
      if d==U: x=0;y=-1;
      if d==D: x=0;y=1;
      t=Snake[0]
      t=(t[0]+x,t[1]+y)
      Snake.insert(0,t)
      del Snake[-1]
      NewApple()
      if Snake[0] in Snake[1:]:  del Snake[2:]
def button_press(button):
      global d
      if button==K_UP: d=U
      if button==K_DOWN: d=D
      if button==K_RIGHT: d=R
      if button==K_LEFT: d=L
      if button==K_w: d=U
      if button==K_s: d=D
      if button==K_d: d=R
      if button==K_a: d=L
def SnakeDraw():
     for i in Snake:
        rect=(i[0]*Scale,i[1]*Scale,Scale-1,Scale-1)
        draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0),rect)
def Score()://＞＞＞＞＞問題の場所1＜＜＜＜＜
     if Snake[0] in Apple:
        print("Yummy")

k=1
while k:
   screen.blit(FIELD,(0,0))
   k+=1
   if k%5==0: tick()
   SnakeDraw()
   AppleDraw()
   Score()
   display.update()
   for e in event.get():
      if e.type == KEYDOWN:
           button_press(e.key)
           if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE): k=0//＞＞＞＞＞問題の場所2＜＜＜＜＜
```

Comment: `NewApple()` 関数でリンゴを食べたかどうかの判定(`if Snake[0] in Apple: ...`)をしていますので、`Score()` 関数で判定を行う時には既にリスト  `Apple` から食べたリンゴの位置座標が削除されてしまっています。

Comment: 参考までに、こちらの環境(`python 2.7.2/pygame 1.9.1/libsdl 1.2.15`)ではエスケープキーの入力でゲームが終了します。

Comment: `pygame` のイベントがどういう物か知りませんが、`e.type == QUIT` の判定が `if e.type == KEYDOWN` の中に入っているのは大丈夫なんでしょうか。